# use CSS Font saved in desktop

Tags: css, fonts

Pretty basic question here, I want to use a font that is saved in my browser and don't have link for it

1. How to check the css rule for the font.
2. How to use it in my website.

Comment: Time to start making use of those dev tools? Also note that unless the font license allows it, you can't just use someone's webfont on your own site. That would be both a copyright violation, and illegal redistribution.

Answer (score 0):

You would most likely have to use `@font-face` and download your font as a `.ttf` or `.woff2` file.
Kind of like this: `src: url("/fonts/OpenSans-Regular-webfont.woff2") format("woff2")`

To apply the `@font-face` to an element, give the element a `font-family` property and set it to whatever you named it in the `@font-face` rule.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
@font-face {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
  src: url(sansation_light.woff); /* change this to your font */
}

div {
  font-family: myFirstFont;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>With CSS, websites can finally use fonts other than the pre selected "web-safe" fonts.</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp

Additional Reference: [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face)

Hope this helped.